# Meteor mapping documents to userId

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor app has the accounts-password package.

```
Meteor.publish('tasks', function () {
  return Tasks.find({userId: this.userId});
});
```

How does Meteor know which document in the 'tasks' collection belong to which user? Do I need to add `ownerId: Meteor.userId` to every collection?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, "yes". There's no magic going on here - the selector just says: "find all of the documents where the `userId` field equals the user id of the caller". It's up to you to make sure the `userId` (or `ownerId` or whatever you want to call it), is correctly written (usually on insert of the document).

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this is via `before` hook on the `Tasks` collection

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Tasks.before.insert(function (userId, task) {
    task.userId = userId;
});

Tasks.before.upsert(function (userId, selector, modifier, options) {
    modifier.$set = modifier.$set || {};
    modifier.$set.userId = userId;
});
```